# Is there any other conic possible?

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, locus

It is told that a conic is the locus of all the points which satisfies the relation.
$$\frac{SP}{PM}=constant$$

Where,

SP = distance of the point from fixed point

PM = distance of the point from fixed line

Which are of 6 types,

1. Point(s) (Finite)
2. Line(s)
3. Circle
4. Parabola
5. Ellipse
6. Hyperbola

Are these the only type of conic possible?

Comment: I believe only these six are possible.

Comment: @Vasili, can you prove your statement?

Comment: There are $9$ types... $3$ of them are empty set (imaginary). But remaining 6 types, real ones, are not as you listed. Because, circle is ellipse.

Comment: The $SP/PM=\text{constant}$ definition is problematic when a focus and/or directrix lies "at infinity", so it actually excludes circles and parallel-line parabolas. Pretty-much the only way to capture all possible types of conic section is via the definition as the solution set of the second-degree equation $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ (where at least one of $A$, $B$, $C$ is non-zero).

Comment: Okay, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there aren't, because we introduce these by cases for example as you said,
$ 1) \ \Delta=0$ gives a line $\\$
$2) \ $ In $\Delta≠0$ we have cases,

$$(A)  \ h²>ab, \ \ (B) \ \ h²=ab, \ \ (C)  \ h²<ab$$

In each cases the locus was similar. So, we named each. For example $(A)$ gives hyperbola, $(B)$ gives parabola, $(C)$ gives ellipse and circle.